# Store a Unity Dependency Injection Container without Service Locator

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, service-locator

I have an application that has lots of external dependencies on hardware systems. I want to unit test the services that interact with these hardware systems so I am abstracting the external portion of each service so that I can replace it with a Mock in the unit test. In the unit test I inject the external dependencies into the constructor of the service.

In my production code I have a central place to register all the external dependencies. Something like this:

```
public class DependencyContainer : UnityContainer
{
    private static DependencyContainer instance;
    public static DependencyContainer Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new DependencyContainer();
            return instance;
        }
    }
    private DependencyContainer() : base()
    {
        RegisterTypes();
    }

    private void RegisterTypes()
    {
        this.RegisterSingleton<IExternalService1, ExternalService1>();
        this.RegisterSingleton<IExternalService2, ExternalService2>();
        this.RegisterSingleton<IExternalService3, ExternalService3>();
    }
}
```

Is this just the Service Locator anti-pattern in disguise or is this a reasonable way to register my dependencies?

Comment: `static DependencyContainer Instance` is indeed "service locator" and  indeed `RegisterTypes()` looks reasonable (very strange that you call it from constructor, but...) which makes the question is very confusing -. Can you please clarify why you think registration itself is a problem? Or maybe you concern about your code actually using `Instance` property? Or?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I figured using the Instance property would fall under the service locator pattern. What is the best way to store this dependency container if not using this pattern?

Comment: Possibly the framework you are using (no idea what you do use) is opinionated about setting up container... Just to clarify "service locator pattern" is for *usage* of `Instance` - if you don't use it to get services from your classes it's just a way to represent single root container (which is fine from my point of view). I don't think it's possible to provide any specific guidance without knowing what you use/trying to achieve... You may want to search on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ for overall questions on architecture level posts about using DI...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks for your help I will likely use service locator for my dependency container in that case. I am building a WPF application with the Prism framework to simplify the MVVM implementation.

Comment: Sound fair. WPF+Prism should have very strong opinion on how to use Unity container (I have not used it so I can't give you guidance). I assume you would not need to use that `Instance` property anywhere but possibly central place of container initialization.

Comment: For anyone wondering there is documentation about the "proper way" to instantiate a   prism based WPF application [here](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/legacy/Initializing.html)